# How to compare char from text file in C?

Tags: c, compare, text-files

I want to be able to perform a check wherein I compare the first character of the input file to a certain character (let’s say `*` in this case) and then print "Hello world" if they do *not* match.

I am able to read in from the file. But `strcmp()` is not letting me compare the input file character and my declared character.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");

    char c;
    char compare[] = "*"

    do 
    {
        c = fgetc(file);
        compare = strcmp(c,compare); //Something is wrong here I think.
        printf("result: %d \n", compare);
    }
    while (c != EOF);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strcmp does not compare a character, it's a loop that compares two character arrays **until** there's a difference between them or both strings terminate with the null character at the same time.

if you want to compare two characters what you want to do is compare the two chars directly as in

```
char * string1 = "string1";
char * string2 = "string2";
if (string1[0] != string2[0])
    puts("hello world");
```

or in your case

```
if (c != compare[0])
    puts("hello world");
```

but since your compare is only one character and you want to only compare 1 character anyways you would be better off just declaring it as a char such as by doing

```
char compare = '*';
...
if (c != compare) 
   puts("hello world");
```

Comment: Awesome it worked. However it only worked when I made my function in this form: "if (c != compare[0])" If i don't put the [0] then the program fails to compile.

Comment: that's because you didn't define compare as a character but rather a character array

the value of a character array is the value of the location of the first character in memory which isn't what you want, you want the value of the first character and therefore have to select it with the square bracket array access semantics

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that instead (it's just to give you an idea) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");

        char c;
        char compare = '*';

        do 
        {
            c = fgetc(file);
            if(c == compare)
            printf("result: %c \n", compare);
        }
        while (c != EOF);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `strcmp` compares two strings. 
You are trying to compare a single character to the null terminated string `"*"`. I am not even sure if this code you have posted will compile, as `strcmp` takes two `char *`'s as parameters, yet you are passing a `char` as the first argument.

Additionally, you are expecting the return value of `strcmp` to a character pointer, but `strcmp` returns an `int`.

Here is a reference on [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). If you are ever unsure about a standard library function, you should use this website. However, in this case, I urge you to find a different, simpler solution to your problem (hint: `strcmp` is unnecessary to compare `char`s), and practice reading compiler warnings/errors!